# How to fix the problem of strange unhandled error in Arcgis python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, arcgis

I'm trying to get started with Arcgis for python. But, I'm getting a strange "Unhandled Error" on jupyter notebook as shown below

> `from arcgis.gis import GIS`

> `gis = GIS()`

> `m = gis.map()`

> `m`

The error is

> Unhandled Error! See the browser console for more info.

[image]

When I try to see the Firefox browser console , I get some strange js errors. The logs are

[image]

I wonder why the error is and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was with the version of arcgis and some default settings of arcgis.

After I updated `arcgis` using `conda install -c esri arcgis`, I enabled the jupyter notebook extension in browser by `jupyter nbextension enable arcgis --py --sys-prefix`. This solved the problem.